# Upload file onto AWS S3 with specific path in NodeJS

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, fs

I've been taking a crack at uploading files onto S3 via NodeJS, but with a specific path where they have to be stored.

```
return s3fsImpl.writeFile(file_name.originalFilename,stream).then(function() {
     fs.unlink(file_name.path, function(err) {
         if (err) {
                console.error(err);
         } else {  /** sucessess **/  }
```

I'm not sure how do I give a path like `/project_name/file_name`.
I have been following [this tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Gv0PJrMDBYc&t=650s)

Answer (score 0):

In this scenario your are using a stream as the target. When you created that stream you should have specified the path at that point.

Comment: `var stream = fs.createReadStream(file_name.path);` and replace path with the path that I want?

Comment: Hmmm, I guess I was reading it backwards. I thought it was a write stream. It looks like the first argument to `writeFile` is the target path, so that's where you would specify the specific path you want. Out of curiosity, why are you using this library instead of the official AWS SDK for NodeJS?

Comment: Apologies for not having described the stream variable. I found a tutorial and I kinda stuck with that since it was doing the job I wanted. It is only now that I'm stuck and faffing around for clues to solve it :)